# ARM diskimage boot "The gues has not initalized the display yet"

Tags: arm, qemu, diskimage

can someone help me with the error "the guest has not initialized the display yet"?

I am using the following details: "sudo qemu-system-arm -m 1024M -sd ubuntu-18.04-arm64-docker.img  -M vexpress-a9 -cpu cortex-a9  -kernel /home/said/GEM5/ARM/fs_images/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_emm -initrd initrd.gz   -append "root=/dev/ram"  -no-reboot"

Comment: This usually means "the guest crashed before it got round to trying to display anything on graphics". For Arm typically serial output is more reliable for early boot stuff. Also, your command line is very suspicious -- vexpress-a9 is a 32-bit CPU, but your filename for the sdcard image suggests it is a 64-bit one...